# category specific most used tags query

Tags: tags

I'm looking to display a list of the top 5 most used tags within a category over 30 days and the top of category.php I found a post that got me almost there but I don't know how filter it by category. Here is what I have:

```
global $wpdb;
$term_ids = $wpdb->get_col("
SELECT term_id , count(*) cont FROM $wpdb->term_taxonomy
INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON $wpdb-  >term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id=$wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
INNER JOIN $wpdb->posts ON $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id
WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) <= $wpdb->posts.post_date AND  $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy='post_tag'
GROUP BY term_id
ORDER BY cont DESC
LIMIT 5
");    
if ( count( $term_ids ) > 0 ) {
$tags = get_tags( array(
    'orderby' => 'count',
    'order'   => 'DESC',
    'number'  => 5,
    'include' => $term_ids,
) );
foreach ( (array) $tags as $tag ) {
    echo '<li><a href="' . get_tag_link ($tag->term_id) . '" rel="tag">' . 
        $tag->name . '</a></li>';
}
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify a bit "most used" ? As in among posts created within last 30 days with particular category?

Comment: I mean tags with the highest count with a specific category.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing this using wp_tag_cloud.

```
global $post;
//Tag Cloud
$cats = wp_get_post_categories( $post->ID );
$args = array(
    'category__in'          => $cats, 
    'showposts'             => -1
);
$custom_query = new WP_Query($args );
if ($custom_query->have_posts()) :
while ($custom_query->have_posts()) : $custom_query->the_post();
    $posttags = get_the_tags();
    if ($posttags) {
        foreach($posttags as $tag) {
            $all_tags[] = $tag->term_id;
        }
    }
endwhile;
endif;

$tags_arr = array_unique($all_tags);
$tags_str = implode(",", $tags_arr);

$args = array(
'smallest'  => 18,
'largest'   => 18,
'unit'      => 'px',
'number'    => 10,
'orderby'   => 'count',
'order'     => 'DESC',
'format'    => 'flat',
'include'   => $tags_str
);
echo '<div class="tag-top"><h4>Popular Tags within: ';
single_cat_title();
echo '</h4>';
wp_tag_cloud($args);
echo '</div>';
```